# C++: Can one overload a constructor with a private constructor with the same parameters?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, overloading

Can one overload a constructor with a private constructor with the same parameters?

Basically if something stores a positive integer, then in the public constructor it would make sure a positive integer was being stored, whereas in a private constructor it doesn't perform the check.

Obviously this example isn't really an appropriate use, but sometimes you want to create an object inside a method and you don't want it to waste time performing full safe initialisation; you may want to just tell it to create something straight away without the special checks (or more prudently heap allocations or something expensive) when you're going to perform them again later or they're just unnecessary, and a method inside the class should be able to use this constructor automatically instead of the other public one with the same parameters.

Comment: I dont think there is such a thing as a private constructor. You could have a private method that is called from the constructor. You can also overload constructors but they must be public.

Comment: @Ben: Okay.  But that's wrong.  You can have private constructors. http://liveworkspace.org/code/41BKrw$1

Comment: I think the official word is *override* not *overload*.  I made the same mistake sometimes.  It can be confusing for some people...

Comment: @Ben, you can have private constructors.  one use is for singletons.  only friends/static members can create.

Comment: @thang: The official word for *what* is override?  As this feature doesn't exist, it doesn't have an official word.  But if it did exist, I can't imagine why it would be termed *override*, since that term is generally used in inheritance contexts, where sub-class functionality replaces base-class functionality.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yea i guess you're right that there is no official word here because it's a nonexistent construct, but I see a lot of people use *overload* in the answers when *override* is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload on acccess like private versus public, but you can overload on the signature: the number of arguments and their types.

Private constructors are quite common.

One usage is for a logically "deleted" constructor (finally directly supported by C++11), and another is for use by a public factory function.

---

Example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A( int const x)
    {
        // Whatever, checked construction.
        // Perform the check of the x argument.
        // Then other things.
        // In C++11 it can be done by checking x and forwarding to the
        // unchecked constructor in the same class. Not shown here though.
    }

private:
    enum unchecked_t { unchecked };
    A( int const x, unchecked_t )
    {
        // Unchecked construction.
    }

    // Methods that possibly use the unchecked constructor.
};
```

Comment: Does the compiler remove the extra parameter from the actual function call or not?  The way you've written it, provided you don't try to convert integers into values of unchecked_t, the extra parameter couldn't be used even if you named it (or rather couldn't be used to add dynamic logic).

Comment: @Veltas: you ask, whether some given compiler with some given options will optimize away the extra parameter. as always the answer to that is to **measure** if it matters (it may happen if e.g. the call is inlined). You assert that the "the extra parameter couldn't be used", well that's incorrect. You further assert "even if you named it", well that's incorrect, there is a named value. You write further "or rather couldn't be used to add dynamic logic", which is pretty meaningless. What the heck is dynamic logic. Maybe you're thinking of using that parameter for *something else*. Don't.

Comment: The parameter isn't named.  By dynamic logic I mean unable to produce different runtime results, or rather to be compile-time determinable.

Comment: I think you can nowadays write `enum unchecked { }`, and don't need the redundant `unchecked_t unchecked`. The dummy value would of course be `unchecked()`

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot overload a public constructor or another member function with a private one: only the name and the parameter types count for the purpose of overload resolution.

To do what you are looking for, define a private constructor that takes an additional `bool` parameter that indicates that the parameter checking needs to be performed:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int x) : A(x, true) {}
private:
    A(int x, bool check) {
        if (check) {
            // Perform the check of the x argument
        }
    }
};
```

To construct an instance and bypass the check, functions that have access to the private constructor call

```
A aUnchecked(-123, false);
```

Checked instances constructed the usual way:

```
A aChecked(123);
```

Comment: the idea of additional argument is good, the choice of `bool` type for that argument is extraordinarly bad. i commonly use some custom `enum` type with just one possible value. a `struct` might also do the trick. you don't have to check the value inside the function body. it's known from the presence of the argument that whatever that argument signifies, is signified.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Not for what the OP describes (checked vs. unchecked): it's perfect for that.

Comment: no, it's maximally imperfect. can't see from calling code what it does. also needs to provide silly argument where it's not needed. also, the runtime checking. ouch.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The calling code is also your code (the second constructor is private) - there's absolutely nothing to see there.

Comment: I'm not sure this is MAXIMALLY IMPERFECT, but I'll agree the other answer looks like it might work better.  I mention checking, but I also note that really I was more concerned about more complicated things happening like memory allocation and complicated initialisation.  The reason why I care more about that is because they actually impact on performance whereas an extra check or two doesn't (if the checks are trivial).  But thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: What's going on with the definition of A::A(int)?  Is it some kind of parameter specialisation?

Comment: @Veltas Good question! If you mean the `: A(x, true)` portion of the `A::A(int)`, it's called a ["delegating constructor"](http://www.nullptr.me/2012/01/17/c11-delegating-constructors/#.UQ-SS1p2FqY). It is a C++11 construct.

Answer (score 1):

with a private constructor you cant instantiate a class directrly instead you used something called named Constructor Idiom.

other thing  you cant inherit the class since the class which wants to inherit will not be able to access the constructor

what you should do is to craete w amethode which is called from the constructor to check

Comment: What is named constructor idiom, then?

Comment: `class A { static A makeNewA(); };`